# Locating a key of a string located in another column

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

I don't know how to fully describe that in English. I will write an example of my TABLE :

```
TLDID   TYP    Whois_Server
1       net    server.net
2       com    server.com
3       org    server.org
```

I have a code which can determine the "TYP" - either a "net"/"com"/"org" from what the user has typed in on the webpage.

```
if (domain.IndexOf('.') != -1)
                    {
                        int kropka = domain.IndexOf('.');
                        string TLDzKropka = domain.Substring(kropka);
                        string TLD = TLDzKropka.Replace(".", "");
                        tldik = TLD;
                        server = db.TLDs.Find(TLD).Whois_Server;
```

Based on the above TLD variable which hold the string i want to find a Whois_Server of the corresponding TYP. I guess I will have to find the TLDID (key) first, then based on that, find the Whois_Server.

However, I receive this :

Arguments types of „Edm.Int32” and „Edm.String” are inconsistent for this operation. - translated from polish, therefore the exact words might be a little off.

I'm using c# mvc and Entity Framework.

How do I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using linq:

```
server = db.TLDs.First(x => x.TYP == TLD).Whois_Server;
```

This is assuming `server` is a string, and `TLD` is one of {net, com, org}.

Comment: @Abbys No problem. Bear in mind `First` will throw an exception if it can't find a record with that TLD.